# Convert NSString to unsigned char

Tags: nsstring, char, unsigned

Hi want to convert my nsstring to unsigned char I have tried with  fallowing line of code

```
unsigned char strTransforms[100] =  (unsigned char) [newTransFarString UTF8String];
```

but its show a error "Array initializer must be an initializer list"

how can I cast it to unsigned char;
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the NSString method – getCString:maxLength:encoding: ?